# how to get rid of the too many systematic if statements in matlab

Tags: matlab, if-statement

I have 2 cell matrix (coming from a certain code):

```
  m1 = GO:0008150'    'GO:0016740'
      'GO:0016740'    'GO:0016787'
      'GO:0016787'    'GO:0006810'
      'GO:0008150'    'GO:0006412'
      'GO:0016740'    'GO:0004672'
      'GO:0016740'    'GO:0016779'
      'GO:0016787'    'GO:0004386'
      'GO:0016787'    'GO:0003774'
      'GO:0016787'    'GO:0016298'
      'GO:0006810'    'GO:0016192'

  m2 ='GO:0008150'    'GO:0016787'
      'GO:0008150'    'GO:0006810'
      'GO:0006810'    'GO:0006412'
      'GO:0016192'    'GO:0003774'
      'GO:0006810'    'GO:0005215'
      'GO:0005215'    'GO:0030533'
```

in each matrix, the first column is the parent of the second one... I need from the code to find the part of graph which can determine all relations between these cells... I have to find cell from column 1 that occurance in column 2, then take the cell from column 1 but from the same row of column 2 and find the similarity between it and onother cell in column 2 .. and so.. it is something like depth first search in graph theory

In general, How can I make a size flexible code (recursive) that can replace the following if statements:

```
for k=1:length(m1)
for ii=1:length(m1)         
for j=1:length(m1)
for i=1:length(m2)
 for e=1:length(m1)
   if isequal(m2{i,1},m1{j,2})
      x1=[m1(j,1) m2(i,2)];
      x11=[x1;x11];
       if isequal(m1{j,1},m1{k,2})
          x2=[m1(k,1),m2(i,2)];
          x22=[x2;x22];
             if isequal(m1{k,1},m1{ii,2})
              x3=[m1(ii,1),m2(i,2)];
              x33=[x3;x33];
                 if isequal(m1{ii,1},m1{e,2})
                 x4=[m1(e,1),m2(i,2)];
                 x44=[x4;x44];
                      .
                      .
            and so..x_total=[x11;x22;x33;x44...]
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
```

Note that the number of if statemtnes are not determined (it depends on m1 & m2 which are also not always constants)

Comment: Can you provide the desired output for the sample `m1` and `m2` in the question?

Comment: why do you have two matices `m1` and `m2`? your question is unclear

Answer (score 3):

A general programming tip is to move the statements that don't change in a loop out of the loop. For example, your "for e=1:length(m1)" loop can be moved to just cover the "if isequal(m1{ii,1},m1{e,2})" statement.
After rearranging the if statements and loops hopefully it becomes clearer how to implement something recursively.

```
for i=1:length(m2)
for j=1:length(m1)
   if isequal(m2{i,1},m1{j,2})
      x1=[m1(j,1) m2(i,2)];
      x11=[x1;x11];
      for k=1:length(m1)
       if isequal(m1{j,1},m1{k,2})
          x2=[m1(k,1),m2(i,2)];
          x22=[x2;x22];
          for ii=1:length(m1)         
             if isequal(m1{k,1},m1{ii,2})
              x3=[m1(ii,1),m2(i,2)];
              x33=[x3;x33];
              for e=1:length(m1)
                 if isequal(m1{ii,1},m1{e,2})
                 x4=[m1(e,1),m2(i,2)];
                 x44=[x4;x44];
                      .
                      .
                 and so..x_total=[x11;x22;x33;x44...]
              end
          end
      end
end
end
end
end
```

Now you can see the recursive function looks something like

```
function x_total=recursive(m1,m2,j,i)
for k=1:length(m1)
   if isequal(m2{j,1},m1{k,2})
      x=[m1(k,1) m2(i,2)];
      xx=[x;xx];
      x_total=[xx;recursive(m1,m2,k,i)];
   end
end
```

This will probably run slow and you may want to look into persistent variables, but hopefully this is enough to get you started. 
(And don't forget to add a condition to end the recursion)